# I always get null when I want to get some data from neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I want to get some data from Neo4j using Spring boot, but I always get nothing. In other words, it seems that java cannot get the data from the neo4j database.

The code is written according to the neo4j Spring tutorial.https://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j/

domain class

```java
@NodeEntity
public class Weather {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_INSTANCE")
    private List<Instance> instances = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_CHARACTERISTIC")
    private List<Characteristic> characteristics = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

repository class

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "weathers", path = "weathers")
public interface WeatherRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Weather, Long> {

}
```

service class

```java
@Service
public class WeatherService {

    private final WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

    public WeatherService(WeatherRepository weatherRepository){
        this.weatherRepository = weatherRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Iterable<Weather> findAll(){
        Iterable<Weather> result = weatherRepository.findAll();
        return result;
    }
}
```

controller class

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WeatherController {

    private final WeatherService weatherService;

    public WeatherController(WeatherService weatherService){
        this.weatherService = weatherService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAll")
    public Iterable<Weather> findAll(){
        return weatherService.findAll();
    }
}
```

And the username and password configuration are in the application.properties.

Could someone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is null? The `Iterable<Weather>`? The properties (`name` ...)? The relationships?

Comment: @frant.hartm sorry...I mean that the iterable is empty. I do have data in the neo4j, but I get nothing from my code.